# Fragment within fragment in an activity as main layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm kinda new in android and I'm developing an application but I am blocked with something:
I have my activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">


</FrameLayout>
```

And this activity contains 1 fragment(drawer_layout_fragment) and my fragment(drawer_layout_fragment) contains another fragment(left_drawer) that is the nav drawer fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_fragment"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="DrawerLayoutFragment">

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:name="NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Everything works fine when I add that fragment to the fragment manager but when I'm in the next view and I clicked back button I'm seeing this error: **Duplicate id 0x7f0d00a5, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d00f4 with another fragment**
I have read that error happens because of I have nested fragments but not sure how can I handle this I have tried added my drawer_layout fragment with the getChildFragmentManager but same error.
And this is how I added my drawer_layout fragment to the fragment manager:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DrawerLayoutFragment fragment = new DrawerLayoutFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();

}
```

And this is the code inside DrawerLayoutFragment that takes me to the next fragment. The only difference is that here I use .replace instead of .add :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.add) {

        NextFragment fragment = new NextFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What is the DrawerLayout() ? .

Comment: What gets you to the next view. can you post that code. Is it an intent?

Comment: Sorry the DrawerLayout is just a fragment I created. I edited and added the piece of code where I'm calling the next fragment And since I'm working with fragments this part I'm using the fragment manager just to replace the previos fragment with the new one.